# How to "find" both regular files and directories?

Tags: find

How can I tell ( if I can tell !) find to find files of both the directory and file type?

```
find -type fd
```

*It is like the heuristic dark ages up in here.*

Comment: Typing the `find` command using that syntax results in this error on Ubuntu: `find: Must separate multiple arguments to -type using: ','` ... for Google.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is the command you can use:

```
find -type f -or -type d
```

Comment: Or `find -type f -o -type d` for POSIX compliant alternative.

Comment: Hey I ran into a little trouble with this when I run $find . -type d -or -type f -and -iname "vision"  it does not do exactly what I expect, am I missing something else!

Comment: -a has precedence over -o, use parenthesis (but escape them for the shell). No need to use the non-standard -or or -and.

Comment: if I try ` find . -type d or -type f -name 'abc'`. I get an error.. `find: paths must precede expression:`.. Any idea why?

Comment: @alpha_989 missing `-` before `or`?

Comment: Yes.. you are right.. It works now.. Thank a lot..

Answer (score 6):

**tl:dr**

use `find . -name "*string*" -type f -o -name "*string*" -type d`

**explanation**

the -o command `or`s the arguments after the filepath completely, such that `find . -name "*string*" -type f -o -type d` computes `find . (-name "*string*" -type f) -o (-type d)`. For this reason, you must specify the

Most users will want something that looks like

```
find . -name  "*string*" -type f -o -name "*string*" -type d
```

which computes as

```
find . (-name  "*string*" -type f) -o (-name "*string*" -type d)
```

**find syntax details**

`-name "*string*"` searches for names that contain the string `string` anywhere in them.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the GNU find then the following solution might suit you:

```
find -type d,f
```

See `man find` for more details:

> To  search  for more than one type at once, you can supply the combined list of type letters separated by a comma `,` (GNU extension).

Comment: Using `GNU find` version 4.7.0.. It doesn't seem to support `,`. The error message says that `find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter.`

Comment: This works on Ubuntu for me, however, for some reason using `-type f -or -type d` or POSIX version `-type f -o -type d` seems to ignore my `! -path` parameter a.k.a. `-not -path` ... Beware to anyone who combines these two parameters, because you might accidentally find/delete files. Use `-type d,f` instead...

Comment: @JesseNickles you need to use parens (escaped) to group the OR clauses: `find ... -not -path ... \( -type f -o -type d \)`. If you don't specify an operator then `-a` (AND) is implied. Since AND binds more tightly, you end up with unexpected behavior in your case.